# LINQ & XNode.DeepEquals running comparisons twice?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, deepequals

I'm using LINQ to compare two XML documents. If a difference is found between two elements I add those nodes to a list which I use to generate a report of differences.

The 'problem' is that if a difference is found it is added to the list twice.

For example, given two simple XML docs:

**Expected:**

```
<Parsed_Data>
  <IntentCount>0</IntentCount>
  .
  .
  .
</Parsed_Data>
```

**Actual:**

```
<Parsed_Data>
  <IntentCount>1</IntentCount>
  .
  .
  .
</Parsed_Data>
```

**And using this code to compare nodes and add them to a list if they're different:**

*The Node class contains two XNodes, one for expected and one for actual.*

```
var expectedNodesRoot = from desc in expected.Descendants("root") 
                        select desc;

var actualNodesRoot = from desc in actual.Descendants("root")
                                select desc;

IEnumerable<XNode> expectedNodes =
               from node in expectedNodesRoot.Elements("Parsed_Data").DescendantNodes()
                select node;

IEnumerable<XNode> actualNodes =
                from node in actualNodesRoot.Elements("Parsed_Data").DescendantNodes()
                select node;

 List<Node> diffList = new List<Node>();
 IEnumerator e = expectedNodes.GetEnumerator();
 IEnumerator a = actualNodes.GetEnumerator();

 while (e.MoveNext() && a.MoveNext())
 {
   var xe = e.Current as XNode;
   var xa = a.Current as XNode;

   if (!XNode.DeepEquals(xe, xa))
   {
     diffList.Add(new Node(xe, xa));
   }
 }
```

**For one difference, this gives me two elements in my diffList:**

```
expectedNode: "<IntentCount>1</IntentCount>"
actualNode: "<IntentCount>0</IntentCount>"

expectedNode = "{1}"
actualNode = "{0}"
```

It seems that DeepEquals compares first the element and then the values. My question is, is there anything in my code that could be causing the duplicates or is this a feature of DeepEquals that I can't do anything about?

I've run tests to see if this always happens and that seems to be the case. So a follow up question would be: Can I count on XNode.DeepEquals to always give me two elements per difference in my List? Confirming this would allow me to continue the work by excluding the second element for each difference, but obviously I can't do that unless it'll always be present.

Comment: What `Node` class/type are you using? Can you provide a link to it's api documentation? All I could find was [node as in a cluster](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.computecluster.node%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How are you populating your `expectedNodes` and `actualNodes`? Text in an XML document are represented as an `XText` which is also an `XNode`. I suspect you're not filtering those out.

Comment: Edited original post to answer your questions.

Comment: Ryan Gates: The Node class contains two XNode objects, one for expected, one for actual. It is not part of any library/framework.

Comment: Just noticed that if I compare two nodes, one empty and one with 1 white space I only get one element in my diffList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in an XML document is exposed as an `XText` (which is an `XNode`).  By going through the descendant nodes, you are going through elements and text.  You probably should be going through elements with no child elements.

```
var expectedElements = expected.Descendants("root")
    .Elements("Parsed_Data")
    .Descendants()
    .Where(d => !d.HasElements);
var actualElements = actual.Descendants("root")
    .Elements("Parsed_Data")
    .Descendants()
    .Where(d => !d.HasElements);
var diffList = expectedElements.Zip(actualElements, (e, a) => new Node(e, a))
    .Where(n => !XNode.DeepEquals(n.Expected, n.Actual))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question perfectly. Your answer also gave me a better understanding of LINQ.